# connecting error mysql db from host to docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a mysql server running on docker container.When I say docker-compose ps I see mysql is up. I have an ubuntu 16.04 host machine. I want to connect to mysql with command line.

I am trying this : 
`mysql --host=localhost --user=abc --password=123 abc --port=3310`

but I am taking this error :

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can      be insecure.
  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through     socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I dont want to go container and connect. And I should use port number 3310. Here is my related docker-compose.yml about mysql:

```
 mysql-db:
        image: mysql:5.7.11
        command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1
        ports:
            - "3310:3306"
```

I am new on these things. How can I connect to mysql? Where I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `mysql -uabc -p` and hit Enter and write the pass...post the output

Comment: I did. Its asking password.  When I type password it is saying : `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Then the MySQL service is not running...try `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: Dont you need the ip address of the docker container rather than `localhost` if you are connecting from the host (guess not a long shoreman)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no you don't. Docker should be exposing on localhost's port 3310

Comment: Can you post the output of "docker ps"?

Comment: here is my `docker ps` output:                                                                                   `fc6cbf8e07ab        mysql:5.7.11                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   11 hours ago        Up 51 minutes       0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp                                                                                        dev_mysql-db_1` for good view : **http://paste.ubuntu.com/23086243/**